Rails: When adding a new enum column to my Postgres DB, why do I have to use change_table (not add_column) in my migration? And is it equally safe?
All the examples of adding a new enum column, which Rails 7 supports, require a change_table to add the column, like:
def up
  create_enum :status, ["draft", "published", "archived", "trashed"]

  change_table :articles do |t|
    t.enum :current_status, enum_type: "status", default: "draft", null: false
  end
end

Are there any differences between this and add_column?  I'm wondering because I'm using strong_migrations, and it requires that I add a safety_assured.  I get this console message:
Strong Migrations does not support inspecting what happens inside a
change_table block, so cannot help you here. Please make really sure that what
you're doing is safe before proceeding, then wrap it in a safety_assured { ... } block.
I don't want it to turn out that doing this inside a change_table rewrites the whole table or does something else that will impact performance on my huge tables in production.

Enums are not just columns. They are a custom data type that is defined in the table DDL. You most likely don't want to actually use them as there is no easy way to add/remove states after the fact and the performance benefits are not worth it. Use an integer or string column.

As for the rest of the question - no there really is very little difference between
using change_table vs add_column in terms of the SQL generated. change_table is really just a more object oriented DSL to do transformations. Both create an ALTER TABLE ...  statement so the performance concerns are kind of irrevant.

@max Eh, looks like they've added better support for changing possible values of the enum.  Thanks for the info!

That still doesn't change the inherent drawbacks of native enum types. Use with caution.
